# Plotting different ranges in X axis in matplotlib / seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm plotting age as x axis, and some other variables in the y axis. In some age ranges I would like to see changes more detailed over shorter periods of time, so I would like to plot something that would look like this:[image]

You can see that some ranges in the x axis (age) have different lengths..

How can I implement this to a list of ages and a list of another variable in python/matplotlib?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want a logarithmic scale?

Comment: yes I'm sure ..

Comment: Then, to make it easier to help, I suggest you post some minimal code to reproduce at least your data and a seaborn plot you attempted (see [MCVE]).

Comment: `fig, (ax, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(ncols=4, gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[1,1,1,3]))` will create 4 axes to which you may plot whatever you like.